# Vue <template> markup not behaving as expected while iterating through a list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have my app.js to generate tabs as below:

Input:

```
<tabs>
    <div>
        <a slot="header">Tab 1</a>
        <article slot="content">
            <h2>Tab 1 Content</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a slot="header">Tab 2</a>
        <article slot="content">
            <h2>Tab 2 Content</h2>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde</p>
        </article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a slot="header">Tab 3</a>
        <article slot="content">
            <h2>Tab 3 Content</h2>
            <p>Neque porro quisquam est</p>
        </article>
    </div>
</tabs>
```

Each `div` above specifies one `tab`. `header` slot being title of the tab nav and the content slot is tab content for respective tab.

With the above input to my `tabs` component I have to generate below output:

Output:

```
<section class="tabs">
    <nav class="tabs-nav">
        <ul class="tabs-list">
            <li class="tabs-listitem">
                <a class="tabs-trigger">Tab 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="tabs-listitem">
                <a class="tabs-trigger">Tab 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="tabs-listitem">
                <a class="tabs-trigger">Tab 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="tabs-body">
        <article>
            <h2>Tab 1 Content</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h2>Tab 2 Content</h2>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde</p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <h2>Tab 3 Content</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </article>
    </div>
</section>
```

With the above input to Tabs how can I get the output as specified above in my render function or Vue template.

If I try to iterate through slots by `this.$slots.header`, I am getting undefined

Could someone please help me to achieve this

Comment: Should you use for loop and generate the tabs?

Comment: Yes @DuongDang. I want use loop to generate the tabs

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: No. I was not able to find @DuongDang. I am still looking for help

Comment: I post a sample code snippet below. Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

This is basic loop in Vue. Hope this helps

```js
Vue.component('tabs', {
  props: ['tabs'],
  template: `
  <section class="tabs">
      <nav class="tabs-nav">
          <ul class="tabs-list">
              <li v-for="item in tabs" :key="item" class="tabs-listitem">
                  <a class="tabs-trigger">{{item.title}}</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="tabs-body">
          <article v-for="item in tabs" v-html="item.content" :key="item"></article>
      </div>
  </section>`
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      tabs: [
        {
          title: 'Tab 1',
          content: '<h1>Tab 1 Content</h1>'
        },
        {
          title: 'Tab 2',
          content: '<h1>Tab 2 Content</h1>'
        },
        {
          title: 'Tab 3',
          content: '<h1>Tab 3 Content</h1>'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <tabs :tabs="tabs"></tabs>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$slots` property contains slots that are *immediate children*, so nested named slots (as you have in your example) would be excluded. In your case, you would only have the `default` slot, containing the wrapper `div`s (i.e., the tabs). In the [`render` function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html), you'd have to manually process the tab's children to get the inner slots in order to generate the HTML you described:

```
render(h) {
  const tabs = this.$slots.default;
  const headers = tabs && tabs.map(tab => tab.children.filter(x => x.data.attrs['slot'] === 'header'));
  const bodies = tabs && tabs.map(tab => tab.children.filter(x => x.data.attrs['slot'] === 'content'));

  if (!tabs || !bodies) {
    return h('div', 'No tabs');
  }

  return h('section', [
    h('nav', { class: 'tabs-nav' }, [
      h('ul', { class: 'tabs-list' },
        headers.map(header => h('li', { class: 'tabs-listitem' }, header)))
    ]),
    h('div', { class: 'tabs-body' }, bodies)
  ]);
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/0x4mr3m560)